# increase size of jvm permanently in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm

I want to increase the size of my JVM permanently rather than doing it manually every time.I tried several options but none of them are working.

```
SET _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms5g -Xmx16g
error        SET: command not found
```

After that i tried small set command.It runs perfectly but when i did java -Xshowsettings:all, JAVA_OPTIONS was set to 1g only

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms5g -Xmx16g
java -XshowSettings:all
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g
VM settings:
Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 910.50M
Ergonomics Machine Class: server
Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

After that i tried exporting.But again error is coming.Please help me out.

```
> export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
> java -jar jconsole.jar &
[1] 28931
Error: Unable to access jarfile jconsole.jar
```

Comment: Make sure that you add the export to your bashrc file

Comment: @xtrakBandit  Can u tell me how to do that.?

Comment: it depends on what shell you're using. Likely you are using bash so in your home directory look for a file named `.bashrc` and edit it. Add `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g` to the bottom

Comment: If you `set` it applies to the current shell.  If you `export` it applies to command you run from the shell as well.  You might not want to set this for all programs as this may prevent you running multiple JVMs at once.